# Determinant of a specific matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $$C_n =\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &\cdots & n-1 & n\\ -1 & 0 & 2 & 3 &\cdots &n-2 &n-1\\ -1& -2  & 0 & 3 & \cdots &n-2 &n-1\\ \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ -1 & -2 &-3 &-4 & \cdots &0 &n-1\\ -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 & \cdots &1-n &0  \end{vmatrix}$$ While computing the determinants for $n = 1,2,3$ and $4$, I think I found the pattern to say that the determinant of $C_n$ is $n!$. So for the general case I started first by doing row$2$+row$1$, row$3$+row$1$ etc ... and got this matrix - $$C_n =\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &\cdots & n-1 & n\\ 0 & 2 & 5 & 7 &\cdots &2n-3 &2n-1\\ 0& 0 & 3 & 7 & \cdots &2n-3 &2n-1\\ \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 & 0 &0 &0 & \cdots &n-1 &2n-1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0 &n \end{vmatrix}$$ I can definitely see the $n!$ forming on the diagonal but I have troubles getting there. I was thinking of using Laplace expansions on the diagonal elements repeatedly, i.e writing it such $C_n$=$1(2(3(...n-1(det(n)))$, but I easily got lost in my tracks and now I have no clue how to move on. Could anyone provide me some help clearing it up? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the determinant of  a triangular matrix?

Comment: @Thomas It suffices to consider a Laplace expansion along either the last row or the first column (repeatedly).

Comment: @ThomasPetit Perhaps you could accept the CW answer below and then this Q will stop showing up as unanswered.

Comment: @almagest Apologies, I was busy after I posted this but hopefully now that's settled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments under the Q:

This matrix is triangular, so it is trivial to compute the determinant: just repeatedly expand by the first column to get $n!$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wasn't sure about whether or not this was a triangular matrix because the notation there made me confused whether or not there were some non-zero elements under the diagonal, which made me hesitate a bit